# How to imagine squared random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let's have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ and two expressions
$$E(X^2 Y^2) \dots E(X)^2 E(Y)^2$$
because they are independent then 
$$E(X^2)E(Y^2) \dots E(X)^2 E(Y)^2$$

Instead of dots i have to place one of three signs: =, <, > or "NOT"

my guess is that answer is "NOT". My idea was to come up with some two examples containing $X_1 \ Y_1$ and $X_2 \ Y_2$ and show that in first example there should be sign > and in second sign <, but i have no idea how to imagine $X^2$. I'd love to hear some advices about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By independence, you have
$$
E(X^2Y^2)=E(X^2)E(Y^2)\geq E(X)^2E(Y)^2.
$$
The inequality above follows because
$$
E(X^2)E(Y^2)- E(X)^2E(Y)^2=E(X^2)E(Y^2)-E(X)^2E(Y^2)\\+E(X)^2E(Y^2)-E(X)^2E(Y)^2\\
=E(Y^2)[E(X^2)-E(X)^2]+E(X)^2[E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2]\\
=E(Y^2)\text{Var}(X)+E(X)^2\text{Var}(Y)\geq 0.
$$
Unless we have a degenerate situation, the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 1):

For any two independent random variables $A$ and $B$, we have that $f(a,b) = f(a)f(b)$.

$E(AB) = \int \int abf(a,b) da db = \int \int abf(a)f(b) da db = \int af(a)da \int bf(b) db = E(A)E(B)$

We also know that for any random variable $A$, we can prove $E(A^{2}) \geq E(A)^{2}$:

$E(A^{2}) - E(A)^{2} = E((A-E(A))^{2}) \geq 0$ since the expectation of $(A-E(A))^{2}$ must be positive or zero. Therefore $E(A^{2}) \geq E(A)^{2}$.

From this we see

$$E(X^2 Y^2) = E(X^2) E(Y^2) \geq E(X)^2 E(Y)^2$$